# Printing arrangements_2 in CGAL vertex-wise

Tags: c++, cgal

So I have a disparate number of line segments which I want to combine to form a polygon. So imagine 4 points `p0,p1,p2,p3` which form a open polygon `p0-p1-p2-p3`. (This is illustrative : the polygon could be closed also)

But my algorithm generates the segments in random order say `(p2,p3) (p0,p1) (p1,p2)`. Hence to combine them coherently I used the **Arrangements_2** class in CGAL.

I have combined them. But now they form a single polygon with an unbounded face. I am not so sure how can I print out the vertex in an orderly fashion.

What I want is the algorithm to output (p0-p1-p2-p3) OR (p3-p2-p1-p0).

I looked at the documentation [link here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.3/doc_html/cgal_manual/Arrangement_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_20.2.2) and they have a nice traversal order for bounded faces but not so much for unbounded faces.

My questions :

1. Can I achieve the same using traversals for unbounded face ?
2. If not **Arrangements_2** what else can I use in CGAL to achieve the same thing ? (The next best thing I can think of is writing a DS myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrangements will certainly do the job.

Once all curves inserted, you can verify that the arrangement has two faces `arr.number_of_faces()`; one unbounded face that has exactly one inner ccb (connected component of the boundary) and another face that has exactly one outer ccb. 
Obtain the first face `arr.faces_begin()`. If it's unbounded `f−>is_unbounded()`, obtain its first inner boundary `f−>holes_begin()`. Otherwise, obtain its outer boundary `f−>outer_ccb()`.